# Is 136 a difference of two rational fourth powers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

There is a rich literature that studies which small positive integers are the sums of two rational fourth powers, see e.g. Section 6.6 of Henri Cohen's book Volume I: Tools and Diophantine Equations. Is there any work that studies the same question for differences? This reduces to the solvability of equation
$$
x^4 - y^4 = nz^4
$$
in integers such that $z\neq 0$. Of course, the question is easy if any of the elliptic curves $x^2 - y^4 = nz^4$, $x^4 - y^2 = nz^4$, $x^4 - y^4 = nz^2$ has rank $0$, but otherwise existence of solution $(x,y,z)=(1,1,0)$ does not allow using local obstruction or (an easy version of) the Mordell-Weil Sieve.

We may assume that $n>0$ is forth-power free, and that $x,y,z$ are pairwise coprime. Then substitution $(s,t,r)=(x+y,x-y,z)$ or $(s,t,r)=((x+y)/2,(x-y)/2,z/2)$ depending on the parity of $n$ reduces the equation to $st(s^2+t^2)=2nr^4$ for coprime $s,t$. This is possible only if $s=au^4$, $t=bv^4$, $s^2+t^2 = cw^4$ for coprime positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $abc=2n$. There are only finitely many such triples, so we get a finite number of equations of the form
$$
a^2u^8 + b^2v^8 = cw^4.
$$
If the corresponding homogeneous equation
$
a^2U^4 + b^2V^4 = cw^4,
$
has no non-trivial solutions, this can often be proved by local obstructions, or reduction to rank $0$ elliptic curve, or the Mordell-Weil Sieve.

The first $n$ for which this method does not work is $n=136=17 \cdot 8$. In this case $abc=17\cdot 16$, which is equivalent to $17$, and there is a problematic case $(a,b,c)=(1,1,17)$, which reduces to equation
$$
u^8 + v^8 = 17 w^4.
$$
The corresponding homogeneous equation
$
U^4 + V^4 = 17 w^4
$
has solution $(U,V,w)=(2,1,1)$, hence we need to study the original inhomogeneous version.

So, is 136 a difference of two rational fourth powers?

**Update**: With the reference provided by Jeremy Rouse in the comment, it is easy to finish the proof that $136$ is not a difference of two rational fourth powers. This answers the question as stated.

In case someone is interested, the next open case is currently $n=219$, for which the problematic case is $(a,b,c)=(3,2,73)$, which reduces to equation
$$
9u^8 + 4v^8 = 73 w^4.
$$
The corresponding homogeneous equation
$
9U^4 + 4V^4 = 73 w^4
$
has solution $(U,V,w)=(1,2,1)$, hence we need to study the original inhomogeneous version.

Comment: FWIW, Mathematica's FindInstance does not find a solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, in 2001, [Flynn and Wetherell proved](https://www.impan.pl/shop/en/publication/transaction/download/product/83714) that the only representations of $17$ as a sum of two rational fourth powers are $(\pm 1)^{4} + (\pm 2)^{4} = (\pm 2)^{4} + (\pm 1)^{4} = 17$. This would address the problematic case mentioned in your post.

Comment: Thank you! With this reference, I can finish the proof for $136$. This answers the question as stated. The next interesting case is $145$.

Comment: In the next case you mention, $n=145$, the equation you write has 4 obvious solutions $(|u|=|v|=|w|=1)$. What do you need exactly to prove? May be that this are the only solutions?

Comment: I meant existence of non-trivial solutions... But this case is now resolved as well.

Comment: We now have been able to answer the question for all n up to 200. The next open case is n=219.